# App Center Push Notifications rate limits

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-push

I have implemented App Center Push notifications in my Xamarin forms app, with several messaging strategies.

1. send same message to list of users.

**Note
The App Center Push to User feature limits notifications to 100 users and up to a maximum of 1,000 target devices.**

In my logic I break the messages into 100 user blocks.

2. send unique message to each user (1 user/push).

My question is there a rate limit on how many times I can hit API per minute, per hour etc?

When sending the individual custom messages and group messages, if i need to send to 1000 users, that's 1000 or 10 API hits.

Or did I miss a way to do this in documentation?

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? I like to send out a message to over 1000 users I don’t know if there’s a way to do it using App center

Comment: I did not get anywhere on this, I built the logic to send individually, but haven't had chance to load test it yet.  I go side tracked with other feature work.  Then also looking at OneSignal which i started using on another app years ago before they partnered with AppCenter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Center is retiring Push Notifications.  Means this is no longer a concern and different path will have to be taken.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/app-center-mbaas-retirement/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that closest you can get as of now - is assigning userIds on SDK side, or using install IDs, and then setting up Push campaigns based on batches of those fields, manually.

Refer to those pages for more details:

[Install ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/xamarin#identify-installations)

[User ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/xamarin#identify-users)